# "Hire a freelancer"-esque site - existing solution or roll our own?

Tags: cms, custom-software, freelancer

We're looking to roll out a kind of "hire a freelancer" style site but on a much smaller scale than existing sites

Is anyone aware of any existing software on the market? haven't had much success googling "freelancer CMS" as you end up with freelancers to hire to build a cms (!)

I'm somewhat tempted to roll our own, but time/budget might be an issue so looking to explore other options.

Thanks for any input !

Answer (score 1):

You should try googling for "open source job board" instead.

Answer (score 0):

[JobberBase](http://www.jobberbase.com/) is an opensource job listing site, if that's what you're looking for.